# Site or/and Sub-site Permission management

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

My manager asking me to Delete/Cleanup user permission for some related sites and subsites. Before I have beckuped (ZIP) all related sites/subsites and delete them using "site settings delete option". Dear community can you please confirm or clarify. If site or sub-site has been deleted it means all permission deleted as well? OR I need to proceed with something else? Thank for support and clarification.

Answer (score 0):

To Delete/Cleanup user permission for some related sites and subsites, you could go to the  User Information list in this site collection. Remove the user from that list would acheive this.

The URL of the user information list is: `http://yoursite/_layouts/15/people.aspx?MembershipGroupId=0`

[image]